# Adding multiple variables in an object - need further assistance

Tags: python, oop

First thing first - upon suggestions, please do your best to be understandable for newbies as if it is too complex, it may not be much useful as I need to furtherly continue after the current ask. Thank you in advance for that :)

I'm trying to define an object with multiple variables that I may use.
So far I was able to create the basic class for myself (with just ID of the object), but I am now struggling to add the rest of the variables needed for the object.

The data that I have to store with the multiple instance of the object is as follows:

- id of the user - this is the value thru which I need to be searching thru the objects as I will have multiple entries of the below example data for different time intervals that I need to count. It does not need to be changed within the objects variables.
- Name - The name of the person for whom I will be counting the hours spent. It is static (does not need to be changed within the objects variables).
- Started timestamp and Ended timestamp - The time within which the person has executed things. As I will have multiple instances of data coming towards the object, I need to check for overlapping of shifts and if so, such hours to be avoided, but if extra hours beside the overlapped - to be added. E.g. if overlapping is not a perfect match, then the additional time spent to be added to the "total spent hours". The data received for both timestamps are in format that I convert into datatime with "datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+02:00')
- Schedule ID - it is the ID of the entry for the started and ended timestamps. It may be saved as an array as it will not be used except for reporting purposes - e.g. the person has processed things during it's first shift (start_timestamp thru end_timestamp).
- Array of contacts that I need to separate to two different values - one for e-mail, other for phone number (including country code). The array returns as **[email, country_code, phone_number]**

Quote of example data that I have:

```
PersonID: ID1234
Name: Anton Todorov
Started at: 2022-12-26T00:00:00+02:00
Ended at: 2022-12-26T02:00:00+02:00
Schedule ID: SCHEDID1
Contacts: ['a.todorov@e-mail.email', 359, '000000000']
---===Separator===---
PersonID: ID5678
Name: Morgan Freeman
Started at: 2022-12-26T02:00:00+02:00
Ended at: 2022-12-26T14:00:00+02:00
Schedule ID: SCHEDID2
Contacts: ['slogan@draftkings.com', 1, '0000000000']
---===Separator===---
PersonID: ID1234
Name: Anton Todorov
Started at: 2022-12-26T14:00:00+02:00
Ended at: 2022-12-27T02:00:00+02:00
Schedule ID: SCHEDID3
Contacts: ['a.todorov@e-mail.email', 359, '000000000']
```

So with that on, I have to calculate the total hours that each person has spend from within these sections of data that I have.

The object that I have so far is as follows:

```
class DataItem(object):
    def __init__(self, person_id):
        self._person_id = person_id

        self._updatable_id = ""

    @property
    def person_id(self):
        return self._person_id

    @property
    def updatable_id(self):
        return self._updatable_id

    @updatable_id.setter
    def updatable_id(self, value):
        self._updatable_id = value

    @updatable_id.deleter
    def updatable_id(self):
        del self._updatable_id


class Persons(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._ids = []

    def find_person_by_id(self, person_id):
        # search by id
        existing = [i for i in self._ids if i.person_id == person_id]

        if not existing:
            # create and append
            existing_person = DataItem(id)
            self._ids.append(existing_person)

        else:
            # assign to existing
            existing_person = existing[0]

        # return the object to be acted upon
        return existing_person
```

So.. Would someone be able to assist me with furtherly developing the object so that I may be storing the data properly inside of each of its instances, please?

I would gladly appreciate all detailed suggestions (especially as soon as I am also able to understand them).

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Is there a reasen you're using a list for `_ids` and not a dictionary? That might make it easier. If you have multiple sets of data per `person_id` you could use a `defaultdict(list)`.

Comment: There is no reason. This is just what I was able to come up with as of my limited knowledge. I'm open for all kinds of suggestions.

Comment: you could read up about the singleton design pattern for your Persons class. Imagine if you instantiate two Persons objects and how your logic of checking the ids would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally developed what I was looking for.
A bit messy, but that does exactly what I need.

Thanks to @Robert Lee for the attempt, despite it was not what I chose to continue with.

```
class PersonData(object):
    def __init__(self, email, country_code, phone_number, user_id, names):
        self._email = email
        self._country_code = country_code
        self._phone_number = phone_number
        self._user_id = user_id
        self._names = names
        self._started = []
        self._ended = []
        self._schedule_id = []

    @property
    def email(self):
        return self._email

    @property
    def country_code(self):
        return self._country_code

    @property
    def phone_number(self):
        return self._phone_number

    @property
    def user_id(self):
        return self._user_id

    @property
    def names(self):
        return self._names

    @property
    def started(self):
        return self._started

    @started.setter
    def started(self, started):
        self._started.append(started)

    @started.deleter
    def started(self):
        del self._started

    @property
    def ended(self):
        return self._ended

    @ended.setter
    def ended(self, ended):
        self._ended.append(ended)

    @ended.deleter
    def ended(self):
        del self._ended

    @property
    def schedule_id(self):
        return self._schedule_id

    @schedule_id.setter
    def schedule_id(self, schedule_id):
        self._schedule_id.append(schedule_id)

    @schedule_id.deleter
    def schedule_id(self):
        del self._schedule_id


class PeopleBuffer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._people = []

    def find_by_id(self, email, country_code, phone_number, user_id, names):
        # search by id
        existing = [i for i in self._people if i.user_id == user_id]

        if not existing:
            # create and append if not found
            existing_person = PersonData(email, country_code, phone_number, user_id, names)
            self._people.append(existing_person)
        else:
            # assign to existing
            existing_person = existing[0]

        # return an object to be acted upon
        return existing_person

    def return_all(self):
        for each_person in self._people:
            print("each_person: ")
            print("Email: %s" % each_person.email)
            print("Country Code: %s" % each_person.country_code)
            print("Phone Number: %s" % each_person.phone_number)
            print("User Id: %s" % each_person.user_id)
            print("Names: %s" % each_person.names)
            print("Started: %s" % each_person.started)
            print("Ended: %s" % each_person.ended)
            print("ScheduleId: %s" % each_person.schedule_id)


class MainApplication(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._buffer = PeopleBuffer()

    def _populate_person(self, email, country_code, phone_number, user_id, names, started, ended, schedule_id):
        person = self._buffer.find_by_id(email, country_code, phone_number, user_id, names)
        person.started.append(started)
        person.ended.append(ended)
        person.schedule_id.append(schedule_id)

    def _print_people(self):
        self._buffer.return_all()

    def main(self):

        while input("Continue? ") != "No":

            user_id = input("Enter UserId: ")
            names = input("Enter Name: ")
            started = input("Enter Started: ")
            ended = input("Enter Ended: ")
            schedule_id = input("Enter ScheduleId: ")
            email = input("Enter Email: ")
            country_code = input("Enter CountryCode: ")
            phone_number = input("Enter PhoneNumber: ")

            self._populate_person(email, country_code, phone_number, user_id, names, started, ended, schedule_id)

        self._print_people()


def main():
    app = MainApplication()
    app.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on what you are doing I would consider doing json data format and do something like this.  Please excuse my quick and dirty code but I think fundamentally you are looking for a way to create a data format that might work for your scenario.

Looking over it one more time, I feel like this might be the format you are looking for

```
[
    {
        "person_id": "ID1234",
        "name": "Anton Todorov",
        "schedule": [
            {
                "schedule_id": "SCHEDID1",
                "started_at": "2022-12-26T00:00:00+02:00",
                "ended_at": "2022-12-26T02:00:00+02:00"
            },
            {
                "schedule_id": "SCHEDID3",
                "started_at": "2022-12-26T14:00:00+02:00",
                "ended_at": "2022-12-27T02:00:00+02:00"
            }
        ],
        "contact_info": {
            "email": "a.todorov@e-mail.email",
            "country_code": 359,
            "phone_number": "000000000"
        }
    },
    {
        "person_id": "ID5678",
        "name": "Morgan Freeman",
        "schedule": [
            {
                "schedule_id": "SCHEDID2",
                "started_at": "2022-12-26T02:00:00+02:00",
                "ended_at": "2022-12-26T14:00:00+02:00"
            }
        ],
        "contact_info": {
            "email": "slogan@draftkings.com",
            "country_code": 1,
            "phone_number": "000000000"
        }
    }
]
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

def main():
    people = list()

    person = dict()
    person['person_id'] = 'ID1234'
    person['name'] = 'Anton Todorov'
    person['schedule'] = list()
    schedule = dict()
    schedule['schedule_id'] = 'SCHEDID1'
    schedule['started_at'] = '2022-12-26T00:00:00+02:00'
    schedule['ended_at'] = '2022-12-26T02:00:00+02:00'
    person['schedule'].append(schedule)
    schedule = dict()
    schedule['schedule_id'] = 'SCHEDID3'
    schedule['started_at'] = '2022-12-26T14:00:00+02:00'
    schedule['ended_at'] = '2022-12-27T02:00:00+02:00'
    person['schedule'].append(schedule)
    contact_info = dict()
    contact_info['email'] = 'a.todorov@e-mail.email'
    contact_info['country_code'] = 359
    contact_info['phone_number'] = '000000000'
    person['contact_info'] = contact_info
    people.append(person)

    person = dict()
    person['person_id'] = 'ID5678'
    person['name'] = 'Morgan Freeman'
    person['schedule'] = list()
    schedule = dict()
    schedule['schedule_id'] = 'SCHEDID2'
    schedule['started_at'] = '2022-12-26T02:00:00+02:00'
    schedule['ended_at'] = '2022-12-26T14:00:00+02:00'
    person['schedule'].append(schedule)
    contact_info = dict()
    contact_info['email'] = 'slogan@draftkings.com'
    contact_info['country_code'] = 1
    contact_info['phone_number'] = '000000000'
    person['contact_info'] = contact_info
    people.append(person)


    print(json.dumps(people, indent=4))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Robert. 
With this, the most important is now to be able to add the 3-rd bunch of information that I have to the record of the first person created - only the started, ended and schedule Id - This is what I find hard to do. 
The contacts info does not need to be a separate list, but that I can already cover from your example. Do you think if you may furtherly develop your answer, please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Since this is not technically a database you can continuously add a "person" to the list of dictionaries indefinitely even if the data has the same person in it.

Comment: I need to be able to have a whole bunch of persons and for each of them to have multiple records for shift start, end and schedule_id. That way the shifts will be grouped by person, instead of separate records for each bunch of data that I have. Once with that, I may loop thru each person and seek when have they worked, how long, etc.

Comment: If that is the case the new method that I posted should be the solution for you.

Answer (score -1):

First things first; Your example feels more like a Java example written in Python. Instance variables are in practice properties, so all of your `@property` methods is redundant code.

---

`dataclasses` module is implemented for cases like yours. For example,

Schedule data class:

```py
# schedule.py

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Union


@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class Schedule:
    schedule_id: str
    start: Union[str, datetime]
    end: Union[str, datetime]
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.start = self._datetime_converter(self.start)
        self.end = self._datetime_converter(self.end)
    
    def _datetime_converter(self, dt: str):
        return datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+02:00')
    
    def overlaps_with(self, other: Schedule):
        return not ((self.start >= other.end) ^ (other.start >= self.end))
    
    @property
    def deltatime(self):
        return self.end - self.start
```

Worker data class:

```py
# worker.py

from functools import reduce
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from .schedule import Schedule


@dataclass
class Worker:
    person_id: str
    name: str
    contacts: str = field(repr=False)
    schedules: set[Schedule] = field(init=False, default_factory=set)
    email: str = field(init=False, default='')
    country: int = field(init=False, default=-1)
    phone: str = field(init=False, default='')
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        self.email, self.country, self.phone = self.contacts
    
    @classmethod
    def add_from_json(cls, worker_id: str, file: str):
        NotImplemented
    
    def overlapping_schedules(self, schedule: Schedule):
        return filter(lambda s: s.overlaps_with(schedule), self.schedules)
    
    def schedule_overlaps(self, schedule: Schedule):
        return any(self.overlapping_schedules(schedule))
    
    def add_schedule(self, schedule: Schedule):
        if not self.schedule_overlaps(schedule):
            self.schedules.update({schedule})
        else:
            NotImplemented
    
    def add_schedules_from_json(self, file: str):
        NotImplemented
        
    def remove_schedule(self, schedule: Schedule):
        self.schedules -= {schedule}
    
    @property
    def total_time_scheduled(self):
        deltas = map(lambda s: s.deltatime, self.schedules)
        return reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, deltas)
        
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(id(self.person_id))
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.person_id == other.person_id
```

In theory you don't really need to create a `Workers` class. The methods `__hash__` and `__eq__` take care of that and you just need to create a `set[Worker]`. However, if you still want to create a `Workers` class, just loop over the existing methods.